# Place Picker is not working in some devices

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using place picker api to show nearby places.

it is working in all the devices except one of the user who has moto x2 device. 
it is not at all launching in this case.

here is the code.

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(RMMeetingActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Kindly help and provide suggestions to improve the given code

Comment: Is there any StackTrace?

Comment: Since i dont have that device , hence i am not able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: He has android 5.1 version

Comment: Without stacktrace no one can help you. test it on Emulator if you do not have a real device  and get the logs .

Comment: I tried with all the devices which i have, and it is working on all. i dont have the device my user have

Comment: Exactly . Thats what i said you can test it on Simulators . Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and get the exact device simulator .